# GCP: how to make sure that gcp project is set in Cloud Shell Editor

Tags: google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I am toying around a bit with GCP cloud shell editor which I start by visiting https://shell.cloud.google.com/?show=ide (which I installed as an PWA) and would like to debug a simple Flask AppEngine app. The app is using Cloud Logging. It runs fine in the terminal window when I first do:

```
gcloud config set project myproject
```

However if I want to use the builtin debugging I get errors because `gcloud config set project myproject` has not been set in that new window. So my question is how do I make sure that `gcloud config set project myproject` is run at startup of each console? I already tried running a `preLaunchTask` but since that is run in a separate console it does not help

Update (26 Jan 2021)
Also toyed around with trying to change the `.bashrc` automatically when opening a project by using a task that is triggered by `folderOpen` and then writes the relevant gcloud command to a script which is called by `.bashrc`as shown below

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
          "label": "Set GCP Project",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "echo \"set -x; gcloud config set project [MYPROJECT]\" > $HOME/set_gcp_project",
          "runOptions": {
              "runOn": "folderOpen"
          },
          "presentation": {
              "reveal": "never",
              "panel": "shared"
          },
          "problemMatcher": []
      }
    ]
}
```

However Cloud Shell does not support these automated tasks. It works fine in VSCode. However it is still a nuisance because if in the GCP console I open a terminal or it opens it when you click on a run in cloud shell it sets the project to whatever project I had last opened in the Cloud Shell Editor

Comment: Running the `gcloud config set project` is not necessary. The environment variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` is already set. Edit your question with details on your debugging environment. For example, if you tool is connecting via SSH, then you will need to setup the environment as part of the SSH session.

Comment: GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT is not set when I open the Cloud Shell Editor. I just have a minimal python flask app. When I open that workspace I would like the editor to set the gcp project such that every console that gets started automatically has the gcp project set.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in customizing your Cloud Shell experience you can always refer to the following section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell).

I guess the must straightforward to always guarantee that the `gcloud config set project myproject` is always run when a new window is opened will be to append that gcloud command at the end of the `.bashrc` file located at your $HOME directory.

Just open the Cloud Shell (make sure you are located at the $HOME directory, which is the default directory that opens up when you open your Cloud Shell) and append the gcloud command by running the following command:

```
[YOUR-USERNAME]@cloudshell:~ (myproject)$ echo "gcloud config set project myproject" >> .bashrc
```

Comment: Adding it to ```.bashrc``` is not really a good option because I have multiple project. So I would like depending on which workspace I open it to set the project automatically

Comment: I guess what would work that every time I open a new workspace that the cloud shell editor write gcloud config set project [myproject] to a script and that script gets called from ```.bashrc```

Comment: I experimented a bit more and used